# Lint rule: Find UClass based on qualified class name

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am writing a lint rule to be used in Android Studio. I want to verify that the return type of certain Kotlin methods is a Class that implements a given Interface.

I can get the qualified name of the return type from the `UCallExpression`.

And I could get the list of Interfaces from a `UClass` object.

But I can't figure out how to get the `UClass` based on a qualified class name.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the qualified name was not the right thing to do in this case.

`UCallExpression.returnType` gives me a `PsiClassType`. I then use the UAST context to find the matching `UClass`.